# Creating Segues Between Tasks Research Kit

Tags: swift, researchkit

I am trying to create a segue between two ORKTasks such as InformedConsent and SurveyTasks. There is not too much documentation in Swift on how to do this? I was wondering if anybody could help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use an `ORKTask` within an `ORKTaskViewController`. Once you have instantiated the controller with its associated task, you can [programmatically present the controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) in any way you choose.

For example: you can use `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, or make it a child of a [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/), or push it into an `UINavigationController`, etc.

Comment: So write now I have a ui tab controller set up one for consent, one for survey, but i want to have it where once the consent task finishes it goes straight to the survey